# When downloading a file from ASP .Net, the file gets appended with HTML content

Tags: asp.net

I am using a REST query to get a file from the shared location using the response, I am creating a temporary file in the webser to store the content of the file. Then I am using the below  code to download a file to client.

```
HttpResponse Response = HttpContext.Current.Response;
Response.Clear();
Response.ClearContent();
Response.ClearHeaders();
Response.ContentType = type;
Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + name);
localStream.Close();
remoteStream.Close();
byte[] attachment = File.ReadAllBytes(Path.GetFullPath("tempAttachment"));
Response.BinaryWrite(attachment);
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

When is use Response.End() i get below error.
    {Unable to evaluate expression because the code is optimized or a native frame is on top of the call stack.}

And when I HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest(); the downloaded file is appended with HTML content of the page.

Please advise how to resolve this issue.

Thanks,
Vikas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't to complete request, just ending response by adding this code

```
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

instead of

```
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

Comment: I was only using Response.End() and used to error. Using both Flush and End solved the issue.